# setState works only on the first item I get from the API

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, here I'm mapping through items I get from an api

```
{this.state.items.map(i => <Item key={i.id} expired={this.state.expired} id={i.id} img={i.img} selected={this.state.selected} name={i.name} price={i.price} getItems={this.getItems} getSelected={this.getSelected} quantity={i.quantity} />)}
```

When I select an item some pop up message comes to confirm the selection or to cancel it, when I click cancel I should fire a cancel function where I rerender the initial state of the item

```
cancel = () =>{
      const initial = {
      selected: false,
      quantities: [],
      select: "SELECT"
    }
    this.setState(initial);         
}
```

But this function only works on the first item on the page, even when I click the first item and confirm the selection, and then select another item and cancel the selection, the selection is just canceled from the first item and not the item I selected in the first place. 
I tried my best in explaining my problem, please let me know if you need more clarification.

function for click handler

```
select = () => {
      let qua = 1;
      let total = qua * this.props.price;
      this.props.getSelected(true);
      const newQuantity = {name: this.props.name, quantity: parseInt(qua), total: total}
      const quantities = [...this.state.quantities];
      quantities.push(newQuantity);
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        quantities : [...previousState.quantities, newQuantity]
      }));
      this.setState({quantity: qua, selected: true, select: "SELECTED", quantityMain: quantities, returnReason: "", returnReasonMore: "", moreInformation: ""}, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state.quantityMain);
      })
}
```

Comment: It sounds like its an issue of your click-handler inside the < Item/> Component. Can you post the code from < Item/> as well?

Comment: You are maintaining a single state variable (`selected`) for an array of items. You should maintain an array for array of items.

Comment: @MarcelT. please check the updated question

Comment: @PrakashSharma the cancel function is inside the item component, so, I think it's a selected state variable for every item

Comment: @Gazzar so why do you have this.
```select = () {```
shouldn't it be 
```select = () => {```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's hard to understand your code, let me know if I'm following you. You have a father component with a `selected` state that render `i` `Item` with this map. You put in the `Item` prop `selected` the father `selected` state. Then you have `i` children instances of component `Item`. The Item component has an state `selected` and a prop `selected` as well, the prop being the same for all the `Item` as it's given by the state of its father. Then, the `select` function call the `getSelected` function that is from the father. Is all that right?